# Media source does not anything

Tags: uwp, windows-media-player

I'm trying to implement a `Media Player Element` in an UWP app but I can't seem to get the `Source` working. When I visit this page, it doesn't show the media player and I can't play it.

#### Code Behind

```cs
public sealed partial class MoviesOverview : Page
{
        public MoviesOverview()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.Movie = SerializationService.Json.Deserialize<Movie>(e.Parameter.ToString());
            SetSource();
        }

        private void SetSource()
        {
            mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri($"ms - appx:///Assets/Movies/{vm.Movie.Title}.mp4"));
        }
}
```

#### Using the Media Player Element

```xml
<MediaPlayerElement x:Name="mediaPlayer" Height="720" Width="1280" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

Comment: I don't think spaces are allowed in "ms-appx://..."

Comment: hi @RomanR. it will throw exception,  If the `ms-appx://` contains blank space.

Comment: Hi @Mout Pessemier Does the following answer work in your side?

Comment: @RomanR. placing spaces between the - or removing those doesn't change a thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Media source does not anything

You could check this line `$"ms - appx:///Assets/Movies/{vm.Movie.Title}.mp4"`. Please don't add blank space in `ms-appx:///`. Then print above uri and make sure the media file exist in `Assets/Movies` folder. `MediaPlayerElement` could not autoplay by default. please set `AutoPlay` property as true like the following.

```
<MediaPlayerElement
    x:Name="mediaPlayer"
    Width="1280"
    Height="720"
    HorizontalAlignment="Center"
    VerticalAlignment="Center"
    AutoPlay="True"
    />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    SetSource();

}
private void SetSource()
{
    mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri($"ms-appx:///Assets/{"test"}.mp4"));
}
```

Comment: I've been trying to get it fixed, even with a hardcoded string to a resource but I just can't seem to get it to play. It doesn't even show the mediaplayer

Comment: Could you try to add the  file path (ms-appx:///Assets/test.mp4) into xaml for testing?

Comment: The problem wasn't with my Uri but with the fact that Visual Studio didn't include these assets, I had to manually include them (didn't know that could). The spaces were the problem there after so thanks!